# SelectableSection is not included in form.values in Eureka form

Tags: eureka-forms

Selected value is not populated into form.values()?

```
form +++ SelectableSection<ListCheckRow<String>>("", selectionType: .singleSelection(enableDeselection: true))
form.last!.header = HeaderFooterView(title: field.comment)
form.last!.tag = field.column_name

for option in options {
   form.last! <<< ListCheckRow<String>(){ listRow in
       listRow.title = option
       listRow.selectableValue = option
       listRow.value = nil
       }
}
```

Thanks